# Integration Problem with a Trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Okay I am a little stuck on this problem.

$$\int \tan^5(x)\sqrt{\sec(x)} \; dx$$

What should be my first step for a u sub or a trig sub? I have tried to use $u=\sec(x)$ and then $u=\tan(x)$, but I get stuck.  A little help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\sec x$. Then $du=\sec x\tan x\,dx$.  Substitute. With part of the substitution done, we are looking at
$$\int \frac{\tan^5 x}{\sec x\tan x}u^{1/2}\,du.$$
Using the fact that $\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x-1$, we end up with 
$$\int \frac{(u^2-1)^2}{u^{1/2}}\,du,$$
that is,
$$\int (u^{7/2}-2u^{3/2}+u^{-1/2})\,du.$$

Comment: I think instead of u^(5/2) it should be u^(7/2) right?  4-.5=3.5=7/2.

Comment: @jack: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\cos x$ then $du=\sin x dx$ and then the anti derivative becomes:

$$\int\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^5}\frac{du}{\sqrt u}$$
now let $u=t^2$ so we find
$$2\int \frac{(1-t^4)^2}{t^{10}}dt=2\int t^{-10}dt-4\int t^{-6}dt+2\int t^{-2}dt$$
I'm sure that you can take it from here.